# Tomcat start and stop using shell script?

Tags: java, linux, shell, unix, tomcat

I have below shell script to stop/stop the tomcat.

```
#!/bin/bash

export BASE=/home/programs/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/bin
prog=jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28

stat() {
if [ `ps auxwwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|wc -l` -gt 0 ]
then
echo Tomcat is running.
else
echo Tomcat is not running.
fi
}

case "$1" in
start)

if [ `ps auxwwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|wc -l` -gt 0 ]
then
echo Tomcat seems to be running. Use the restart option.
else
$BASE/startup.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null
fi
stat
;;
stop)
$BASE/shutdown.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null
if [ `ps auxwwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|wc -l` -gt 0 ]
then
for pid in `ps auxwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|tr -s ' '|cut -d ' ' -f2`
do
kill -9 $pid 2>&1 > /dev/null
done
fi
stat
;;
restart)

if [ `ps auxwwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|wc -l` -gt 0 ]
then
for pid in `ps auxwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|tr -s ' '|cut -d ' ' -f2`
do
kill -9 $pid 2>&1 > /dev/null
done
fi
$BASE/startup.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null
stat
;;
status)
stat
;;
*)
echo "Usage: tomcat start|stop|restart|status"
esac
```

Now above script works with local tomcat. Now how can i modify above script to stop/start **remote tomcat**?

Thanks!

Comment: Is not clear what you want, A bash script to start tomcat from another machine?

Comment: morgano, i can run the script from my machine. But the script should start/stop the tomcat located in remotely .Tomcat is not in my machine.

Comment: using a ssh session? using a daemon listening on the remote machine?

Comment: morgano, i have tomcat installed remotely. I need to write a script which will start/stop remote tomcat from any system.I really dont know how to do it. I found above script by googling around. What should i do to start/stop remote tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ssh` to execute a local script on the remote machine to start/stop Tomcat, so if you are in a linux terminal, you could do something like:

```
ssh username@remoteMachine /home/username/myScipts/start_tomcat.sh
```

where `start_tomcat.sh` would be a script in the remote machine, of course you would need a valid username/password on the remote machine, and also the remote machine would need to have sshd installed and running

Comment: morgano, ssh means Putty?

Comment: morgano, the start_tomcat.sh script will not be in remote machine. Script will be in my local machine but tomcat instance is running in remote machine.

Comment: yes, you could use Putty if your local machine is Windows, the command line I put on my answer is only for a unix terminal

Comment: morgano, start_tomcat.sh script will not be in remote machine. Script will be in my local machine but tomcat instance is running in remote machine

Comment: Ok, just think about it, How would you tell tomcat to start on a remote machine if Tomcat is not running and hence not listening in any port to receive your "start" command? as far as I can tell your local machine is a Windows, right? in this case then you need a ssh client in command line for windows, and then you need to create a *.bat or *.cmd script that uses that ssh client

Comment: I am using Windows 7, and I have a remote Linux machine that has Tomcat (on port 8080). Now i need to write a script to start/stop the tomcat running on remote linux machine.